# How to use HTML5 inputs in Rails 3.2.12

Tags: ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

is it possible to use HTML5 input type date for a Ruby and Rails 3.2.12 form?

When its possible how can I use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server-side solution has nothing to do with your client-side solution. If tomorrow browsers support a new input type called Ray, then it doesn't matter whether or not Ruby supports it. Your form will send the data as an HTTP POST which Ruby, and any other decent server side app, can process.

Comment: I've found this `<%= select_date() %>` but when I try to use it I got this error: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

Comment: I have no idea what that is. :) If it is Ruby code, then you need to edit your question to focus on that, or close this one and ask a new one.